# Public Arraylist size shows different in 2 places in Android Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a public ArrayList that i want to store a users ID in, when I store the person ID's, it seems to show the arraylist just fine in the getContacts function, but when I later have my onclick function working for lists, the position integer seems to work fine, and I have tested it with toasts, now all I need is something like chatids.get(position), but it keeps returning the array (chatids) as empty.

Here is my code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    public ListView contacts;
    public ArrayList<String> chatids = new ArrayList<String>();


    // User Setup Defaults
    String server = "https://xxxxxxxxx";
    String suser = "xxxxxxxx";
    String spass = "xxxxxxxx";

    public void getContacts(final aConAdapter adapterss) {
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = server+"/xxxxxx/?username="+suser+"&password="+spass+"&getcontacts=yes";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.v(TAG, "I recieved: " + response);
                        ArrayList<String> chatids = new ArrayList<String>();
                        try {
                            JSONArray parseContacts = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int x = 0; x < parseContacts.length(); x++) {
                                JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parseContacts.get(x);
                                aConMan newUser = new aConMan(array.get(0).toString());
                                adapterss.add(newUser);
                                String newUser2 = array.get(1).toString();
                                Log.v(TAG, newUser2);
                                chatids.add(newUser2); // This is working, i compared it and it shows as size is 2 when logging
                                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Error: "+e);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Oops, an error occurred"+error);
                aConMan newUser = new aConMan("VolleyError: "+error);
                adapterss.add(newUser);
                aConMan newUser3 = new aConMan("Your internet may have issues.");
                adapterss.add(newUser3);
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ArrayList<aConMan> ourlist = new ArrayList<aConMan>();
        aConAdapter adapter = new aConAdapter(this, ourlist);
        final ListView contacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contacts);

        getContacts(adapter);

        //CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        //contacts.setAdapter(customAdapter);



        contacts.setAdapter(adapter);

        contacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = contacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(chatids.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // This still shows 0, no error or anything wrong, i want to debug it by getting the size of the result, it should be 2 if the user has 2 contacts (which shows up fine on the UI display).
            }
        });
    }

    public class aConMan {
        public String defusername;

        public aConMan(String defusername) {
            this.defusername = defusername;
        }
    }

    public class aConAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<aConMan> {
        public aConAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<aConMan> aconman) {
            super(context, 0, aconman);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            aConMan aconmans = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tvUname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            tvUname.setText(aconmans.defusername);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the contents of chatids getting updated on the getContacts function, but on the onClick listener it doesn't! Thanks, help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `chatids` defined both as a global variable and a local variable. Remove the local variable.

The local variable is in your `onResponse()` method:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    //...
    ArrayList<String> chatids = new ArrayList<String>(); //remove this
    //...
}
```

Comment: I see the global variable I defined, but where is the local variable, I am confused?

Comment: +1 it worked! Thank you, I thought that that would erase the variable, but it doesnt matter (yet), do you know how to dump the contents of an ArrayList, would be great if you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Dump the contents?

Comment: I mean say I have some content in my ArrayList, how would I remove all items in the array, so say it contains {"one","two"}, how can I remove these strings (pretending I don't know about this, and just make it {}? I need to do this later.

Comment: Thats what I saw but in one post it says that I have to define the function manually (I think)? I will try again tomorrow, goodnight and thank you.

Comment: No, it's a function that's included in the ArrayList already.